# why is 'bot' invalid. in my discord.py code

Tags: discord.py

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, self_bot=True)

    @commands.check(self_check)
    @bot.command(pass_context=True)
    async def mall(ctx, *, message):
        await ctx.message.delete()
        for user in ctx.guild.members:
            try:
                await user.send(message)
                print(f"{user.name} has recieved the message.")
            except:
                print(f"{user.name} has NOT recieved the message.")
        print("Action Completed: mall")

bot.run(token, bot=False)
```

And i get an problem like this:
`invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 45)`

Why is 'bot' invalid syntax. I dont get it

Comment: The code you have posted doesn't have 45 lines, also the padding is not correct

Comment: i know i deleted some lines in the message. it says ```    bot.run(token, bot=False)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax``` but in my codeeditor it is in line 45

Comment: Double check all your indentation, and make sure that the line before this one is also correct.  If that doesn't work, make sure your question contains a [mcve] so we can copy your code and get the same error

Comment: It works right now. Didnt know what was wrong but it works

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually make a prefix... `prefix='Enter prefix here'`

Also `bot.run(token, bot=False)` needs to be `bot.run('Enter token here')`

Answer (score 0):

1. We don't know what is "line-45"
2. You didn't define "token" & "prefix"
3. Never saw params like `self_bot=True` or `bot=False`